# Why do the examples in Tomcat8's webapps package fail with "not found" and "NullPointerException" errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I have just installed Apache Tomcat 8 to an Amazon Web Services instance.  In order to study some sample Tomcat deployments I also installed the "examples" using the command `sudo yum install tomcat8-webapps`.  I can now view the main Tomcat server page at port 8080, but when I attempt to access the examples at **http://localhost:8080/examples/index.html**, a page appears with the messages:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /examples/index.html
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.32

The log file `/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.2018-10-27.log` shows:

```
27-Oct-2018 10:58:49.791 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I get the examples to work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mike Moore](https://blog.yo1.dog/fix-for-tomcat-8-examples-webapp-nullpointerexception/),

> some properties that used to be defined on the Context level now must
>   defined on the Resources level.

The solution to this problem is therefore to modify `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/examples/META-INF/context.xml`, changing its `Context` stanza from

```
<Context allowLinking="true"/>
```

to

```
<Context>
  <Resources allowLinking="true" />
</Context>
```

Then restart Tomcat and access to the `/examples` directory becomes functional.